# Why is java.io.FileSystem package-private?

Tags: java, reflection, io

I came across this class `java.io.FileSystem` and noticed it has many methods that I currently need in my project. However the class is package-private, and so I am accessing the needed methods using reflection.

Questions:

1. Is there any particular reason why this class is marked package private?
2. Are there any dangers of accessing it via reflection? (Other than performance hit, that is.)

Comment: I am curious to know what methods you are hoping to use.

Comment: @pd40, `canonicalize`, `normalize`, `resolve` etc.

Comment: @pd40, also there are a bunch of convenience methods that IMO should be publicly available (`rename`, `createDirectory` etc).

Comment: Is http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html an option? I would be hesitant to depend on private methods as your code will break if the internal implementation changes.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you would rather use reflection to accomplish this than use the `File` methods which use `FileSystem` to accomplish the same task?

Comment: @missingfaktor Why would you do that, when the `Path` class has all those methods anyhow?

Comment: @pd40, I am trying to avoid external dependencies as much as possible. (Such are the requirements.) However if that's the only reliable way to go for, I will go for it. In any case, I would like to know the answers to the questions I have asked.

Comment: @Jeffrey, take a set-difference of functionality provided by `FileSystem` and and the functionality provided by `File`. The result of this operation represents an area I am interested in.

Comment: @Voo, `Path` class is in Java 7. We are using Java 6.

Comment: @missingfaktor Oh I see, well the Java6 files API is basically useless, so I'd go with an external dependency then or use Java7 - the new API works fine.

Comment: @Voo, see my comments in response to pd40.

Comment: @missingfaktor [`canonicalize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalFile()) is included as a method of `File`. Both `normalize` and `resolve` are invoked during the construction of `File` instances.

Comment: @Jeffrey, I _need_ `normalize` and `resolve`. (Sorry, I cannot elaborate on the specifics of my use case here.)

Comment: @missingfaktor Why can't you just create new `File` instances to do it for you? I'm sure the overhead of creating new `File`s is still less than the overhead of reflection.

Comment: @Jeffrey, what I said in my previous comment.

Comment: Wow, three downvotes, and not a single comment explaining what's wrong with the question.

Comment: check the [source of `File`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/File.java.html) (search for the methods you need to use). All are exposed somehow, so you don't need to use FileSystem directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. This class is package private because SUN (and by extension, Oracle) believe that the methods of this platform-dependent class are likely to undergo significant change in the future, and therefore must not be accessible directly. All implementations of this abstract class are in native code; Java programmers should not be able to create their own.
2. The biggest danger of using a hidden class through reflection is not the performance, but a very real possibility that its methods or even the entire class would disappear in the  next upgrade of the JDK, no matter how minor. Non-public APIs are, well, non-public; changing them is fair game even in a maintenance release, so you have only yourself to blame if your program stops working after what seemed like a routine JDK update.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any particular reason why this class is marked package private?

Overall, the purpose for declaring a Java SE class to be package private is to tell you that it is not an API you should use.

In general the reasons are:

- To make it easier for the Java team to make *breaking* changes to the (internal) API in future releases.
- To hide restrictions / limitations that make the APIs unsuitable for general use.  For example:

  - There might be security implications, or a risk that your calls will "break" something else.
  - The behavior of the methods might just be too messy, or too platform dependent to explain in the javadoc.

In this case, I suspect that the designers thought that both reasons applied.  But note that debating the "correctness" of their (assumed) original thinking is moot.  (And off-topic: StackOverflow is not a discussion site.)

Now the Java team's thinking on file system access and portability has evolved over time.  In Java 7 they introduced some new APIs (e.g. `java.nio.file.Path` and `java.nio.file.FileSystem`) that handle the issue of file system specific behavior much better than the old `java.io.File` API.

However, that doesn't mean that they could or should to retroactively change or remove the old APIs.  It would break "millions" of existing Java applications if they did that.

> Are there any dangers of accessing it via reflection?

The reasons I listed above would also apply if you use the methods reflectively.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any particular reason why this class is marked package private?

Yes. `java.io.FileSystem` is not part of the Java API. There is no guarantee how and if it will work. It might be removed or changed in next versions. In fact it's most likely missing in every Java implementation other than Oracle's.

`java.io.File` uses this class internally, so it should expose most of its functionality in one way or another.

> Are there any dangers of accessing it via reflection? (Other than performance hit, that is.)

You are avoiding `SecurityManager` so it won't work with that.